# Sort or filter object arrays based on data members

Tags: c++, sorting, minimum

Is there a standard method of sorting or filtering an array of objects based on their data members or member functions?

I'm looking for a standard function like `getLowestValue` in the code bellow:

```
class Grade
{
public:
    Grade() : _grade(0) {}

    void setGrade(int i) { _grade = i; }
    int getGrade() const { return _grade; }

private:
    int _grade;
}

int main()
{
    Grade grades[10];

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        grades[i].setGrade(generateRandomNumber());

    Grade *lowestGrade = getLowestValue(grades, Grade::getGrade); //???

    std::cout << "lowest grade: " << lowestGrade->getGrade() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The [`std::min_element()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) function is purposed for this.

Comment: Do you want to sort, filter, or find the lowest value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To sort you can use [`std::sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and to find the minimum [`std::min_element()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element).

In both cases you will have either to implement the `operator<` or to create a comparison function.

Example of `operator<`

```
inline bool operator< (const Grade& left, const Grade& right){ 
    return left.getGrade() < right.getGrade();
}
```

Usage of `std::min_element()`:

```
Grade result = *std::min_element(std::begin(grades), std::end(grades));
```

Usage of `std::sort()`:

```
std::sort(std::begin(grades), std::end(grades));
```

You will have to include: `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: I this line: `inline bool operator< (const Grade& left, const Grade& right)` I get error: `error C2804: binary 'operator <' has too many parameters`

Comment: @Pilpel your operator should be defined outside of the class

Comment: @Pilpel A very detail response can be found in the "Comparison operators" section of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Answer (score 1):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

The standard way to sort anything is to use `std::sort()` with an comparison function passed to it.

```
std::sort(grades, grades + 10, [](Grade a, Grade b) {return a.getGrade() < b.getGrade();} );
```

If comparing between objects is something you'll be doing often, it might be a good idea to implement the `operator<` in your class. That way, you don't need a comparison function.

Answer (score 0):

> *"Is there a standard method of sorting or filtering an array of objects based on their data members or member functions?"*

There's a number of functions available from the [c++ standard Algorithm library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). Namely

- [`std::min_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element)
- [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)
- [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)
- [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

to realize the functionality you mentioned (Examples of usage are given in the reference pages).

You'll have to provide appropriate comparator functions/classes that operate on your structure members. These can even be lambda functions, if you want to write them on the fly.